# Multiple and conditions for ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I was trying to use Multiple conditions with and operator in angular to assign a class, but its not working.

```
<div class="kt-btn" ng-class="{'aDisabled': ((user.firstName.length<2)&&(user.lastName.length<2)&&(user.isOperator<2)&&(user.userName))}"></div>
```

Comment: What happens if you put that logic into a controller?

Comment: how can we call function for  ng-class?

Comment: <div class="kt-btn" ng-class="getClass(user)"></div> and in $scope.getClass = function(user) { return ((user.firstName.length<2)&&(user.lastName.length<2)&&(user.isOperator<2)&&(user.userName)) ? 'aDisabled': ''; };

Comment: All the scope variables are functions. So you can do something like ng-class="getClassName" and have same named scope variable in controller

Comment: But this is not dynamic. when i will update textboxes

Comment: if `user.firstname` is null then it'll through error

Comment: can you provide other controls of the form which models are `user.firstName..user.userName`

Comment: use  ng-class="{'aDisabled': user.firstName.length<2 && user.lastName.length<2 && user.isOperator<2 && user.userName }"   No need the brackets.